# What are the chances of finding power armor in the wasteland?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've reached maximum vault dweller capacity for a while now and in my journey to the top, never have I once found power armor while exploring the wasteland. I have come across many +7 outfits, but never power armor. Am I just super unlucky, and then what are the chances/probability of coming across one?